# Programatically saving a excel file from the web page

Tags: c#, winforms, excel

I have a web page which displays some report. When I click on the link for excel, it puts all the data that is displayed on the screen into a CSV file and opens a File Download window which lets me either Open, Save or Cancel.

I want to download this file to a specified location programatically without the user seeing the File Download window. I am using a Windows Application. I dont have the code for the website displaying this report hence dont have the dataset. Also, I looked into the HTML that gets generated by doing a view source on the page but I can't really scrape through it to get the data.

Hence I need to know how to download an excel file from a given website to a location on my computer.

Thanks in advance

Rita

Answer (score 4):

Well you'll need to find the appropriate link or post action. You can then use something like:

```
string url = "http://whatever/.../foo.xsl";
string target = @"c:/excel documents/foo.xsl";
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(url, target);
```

It gets a bit more complicated if you need to authenticate etc though.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're showing the web page within a WebBrowser control.  You can handle the [WebBrowser.Navigating Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigating.aspx) and inspect the value of the [WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowsernavigatingeventargs.aspx) URL property to see if string.EndsWith(".csv", CurrentCultureIgnorecase) (or perhaps a more specific test).

If you detect that the link that has been clicked is for a file you wish to download then you can call e.Cancel() = True on the WebBrowserEventArgs instance to stop the browser from proceeding with its normal behavior of opening the File Download dialog.  Then you can use .NET's [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) and [HttpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx) classes to manually download the file.

[Here's a sample of downloading using these classes](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/bfarley/simplewebfiledownload11162005015304AM/simplewebfiledownload.aspx)

Comment: I'd take Jon's advice of using the WebClient class rather than my suggested HttpWebRequest/Response.  The WebClient wraps the Request/Response objects and for these scenarios is quite a bit easier to get up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am doing a screen scraping, so I am not displaying the web page.

What I have done is gone to the URL where the report is displayed on the screen. There is a hyperlink for 'Excel'. I make this hyperlink click from my program itself. On clicking this link, it opens the File Download dialog box.

I have written, the WebBrowser.Navigating and Navigated events, but the control does not come here. Any ideas

1 more thing, the site that I am accessing is java website.